# Can't send emails with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer like this:

```
 const from = "info@my_domain.com";
 const to = 'some_mail@gmail.com';
 const subject = 'my subject';
 const html = '<b>Hello world</b>';

 const smtpOptions = {
   "host": "mail.my_domain.com",
   "port": 587,
   "secure": false,
   "auth": {
     "user": "info@my_domain.com",
     "pass": "12345679"
   },
 }

 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpOptions);

 try {
   const a = await transporter.sendMail({
     from,
     to,
     subject,
     html
   });
 } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
 }
```

and I get this error:

> Error: self signed certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure
> (node:_tls_wrap:1532:34) at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) at
> TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:946:8) at
> TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:727:12) {  code:
> 'ESOCKET',  command: 'CONN' }

although I have a valid ssl and after some research I came up with adding this line to the smtpOptions :

```
tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

Now I don't get the error but no email is send !

Why I get this error and How to fix this so that I can simply send emails ?

Comment: please be aware that `from` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a variable name

Comment: From my understanding, the error you are getting indicates that the SSL cert on your domain is invalid. If you have just added the SSL cert you may need to wait a few hours before it propagates with the domain registrars. 

you can also try disabling your anti virus with `rejectUnauthorized: false` (reference: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/406#issuecomment-83941225)

Comment: Also please note that using Gmail is not the preferred way to send emails with nodemailer: https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Comment: @Michael Sorensen my SSL is Cloudflare full SSL and I think it's valid. and yes I added it a few minutes ago... so I wait and come back to you a couple of hours later